# Show div initially: Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to replace divs on click. For that , i am using following script

```
$(function(){
var $containers = $("#center > div").hide();

$('div span a').each(function(i,el){
  var idx = i;
  $(this).click(function(e){
    var $target = $containers.filter(':eq(' + idx + ')');
    // Fade out visible div
    if($containers.filter(':visible').not($target).length){
      $containers.filter(':visible').fadeOut();
    }
    // Fade in new div if not already showing
    $target.not(':visible').fadeIn();
    e.preventDefault();
  })
})
});
```

html code is

```
<div>
 <div>
<span><a href="#">Home</a></span>
  <span><a href="#">About us</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Specifications</a></span>
<span><a href="#">Contact us</a></span>
</div>
<div id="center">
<div class="container">
Hey , this is Home div contents

</div>
<div class="container">
 Hey , this is About us div contents

</div>
<div class="container">
 Hey , this is Specifications div contents

</div>

<div class="container">
 Hey , this is Contact us div contents

  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here all divs are hidden initially. I want to display the 1st div and other divs on click accordingly

Please help,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[:first](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_first.asp)** selector

**Example :**

```
$(function(){
    var $containers = $("#center > div").hide();
    $("#center > div:first").show(); // OR $containers.first().show();
            // existing code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
var $containers = $("#center > div").hide();
```

With this

```
var $containers = $("#center > div").not(':eq(0)').hide();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uVuG5/)

Answer (score 1):

1) Hide all divs except first

2) On tab click, fade out all divs, and fade in the one that corresponds to the clicked index

```
$("#center").children().not(':first').hide();

$('div span a').click(function(ev) {
    $('#center').children().fadeOut().eq($(this).parent().index()).fadeIn();
    ev.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just replace

`var $containers = $("#center > div").hide();`

with

`var $containers = $("#center > div").not(':first').hide();`

Answer (score 1):

Try Like This

```
$(function(){
var $containers = $("#center > div").not(':eq(0)').hide();

$('div span a').each(function(i,el){
  var idx = i;
  $(this).click(function(e){
    var $target = $containers.filter(':eq(' + idx + ')');
    // Fade out visible div
    if($containers.filter(':visible').not($target).length){
      $containers.filter(':visible').fadeOut();
    }
    // Fade in new div if not already showing
    $target.not(':visible').fadeIn();
    e.preventDefault();
  })
})
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var $containers = $("#center > div").hide();
$containers.first().show()

$('div span a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var ind = $(this).parent().index();
    $containers.fadeOut().filter(':eq('+ind+')').fadeIn()
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kCa6w/